# Why does this code not work when i change the functions names?

Tags: python

I saw this code on a website, it's use was to monitor the keyboard for any key getting pressed and then it would print the statements which are written below.
the thing is, whenever I change the functions names, it just... stops working!

Basically when I change the `on_press` and `on_release` to things like `key_pressed` and `key_released` and then change the `on_press` and `on_release` in the button lines (in the listener variable) to the names I defined , the code runs without any error , but whenever I press any key on the keyboard , it just writes the assigned character and not the whole statement. Why?

```py
def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False

listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
```

Comment: You have to indicate exactly what you're changing and how it impacts the result... Otherwise we have no way of knowing what the problem is...

Comment: You can only change **your** function names, not the names of the input parameters which you assign them to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to do this:

```
listener = keyboard.Listener(
   key_pressed=key_pressed,
   key_released=key_released)
```

The above will not work, you cannot change the keywords ("keyword=value") on the Listener-function.

The code below should work:

```
listener = keyboard.Listener(
   on_press=key_pressed,
   on_release=key_released)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the keyboard documentation: https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html. Basically the `Listener` expects the function names in a specific way, otherwise it won't work.

That means you cannot change the function names.